# Create stacks of groups of files in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to combine groups of files in stacks for each group. I have been trying few things, but I cannot figure out how to group them and make sure each group is stacked properly. So, I have a list of files like this:

```
 file_011-001.txt

 file_011-002.txt

 ...

 file_011-010.txt


 file_012-001.txt

 file_012-002.txt

 ...

 file_012-010.txt


 file_023-001.txt

 file_023-002.txt

 ...

 file_023-010.txt
```

How would you combine each group in a single stack like this:

```
 file_001_stack.txt

 file_002_stack.txt

 file_003_stack.txt
```

or like

```
 file_011_stack.txt

 file_012_stack.txt

 file_023_stack.txt
```

Thanks all for helping.

Comment: Huh? Stacks of groups of files? Can you please explain better - I am confused!

Comment: group A has ten files and group B has another ten files. I want to group together all the file which belong to A in one file and do the same for B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in file_[0-9]*-[0-9]*.txt; do
  cat "$f" >> "${f%%-*}_stack.txt"
done
```

Comment: It does work! Honestly the name of my file is much more complex (file_[0-9]*_[0-9*]_[0-9*]-[0-9]*-{0001..1000}). I do understand the meaning of f%%, but I really don't get -*. I have tried different combinations f%%-* like f%%-*-*, f%%_*-*-* and they all lead to the same result. Anyway, THANKS for helping.

Comment: `f{%%-*}` removes from `$f` value the longest string matching `-` follow by any character `*` (see [Delete a pattern from the end of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/502/shell-parameter-expansion/7579/delete-a-pattern-from-the-end-of-a-string#t=201609230821207796154).